# More "request for member in not a structure or union" errors

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm using coocs2d and I get the title errors when commented. I imported UIKit into my header.

```
-(void)timerLoad:(NSTimer *)timer {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(timerLoad:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    if (loadingBar.loading) { //error
        [activity stopAnimating];
    }
    else {
        [activity startAnimating];
    }
    if (loadingBar.loading = NO) { //error
        activity.HIDDEN = YES; //thanks ;)
    }
}
```

loadingBar is a CCProgressTimer and
activity is a UIActivityIndicatorView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you imported the `CCProgressTimer.h` header file into this implementation file? If all you do is a forward declaration (`@class CCProgressTimer`) then it tells the compiler that a class with that name exists, but it doesn't tell the compiler about the class' properties. You must have the header imported for dot syntax (`loadingBar.loading`) to make sense to the compiler.

(Also, `UIView` has a `hidden` property, not a `visible` property.)

Comment: Good call Jonathan. That visible/hidden stuff always gets me, since I came from C#.Net.

Comment: Thanks I changed visible to hidden. I also imported CCProgressTimer but that didn't do anything to the errors. #import btw haha

Comment: What's the actual output from the compiler?

Comment: You mean the compiling error? It's Request for member 'loading' in something not a structure or union.

Comment: Then is `loadingBar` of some other type? Are you sure it has a `loading` property?

Comment: Not sure about that. It's just a CCProgressTimer that's supposed to be loading and changing scenes when it's 100%. It's a splash scene basically. Would you like more detailed code?

Comment: Where is it declared? What does the declaration look like? After you've found that, check what the type on that declaration has in terms of properties by viewing the relevant header file.

Comment: #import "CCProgressTimer.h" I'm not sure that it's a problem with that though. I'm getting errors most likely because I have my @interface as ClassName : CCLayer because I'm using cocos2d

Comment: No, the declaration of the type, not the import statement. Go look at the actual definition of `CCProgressTimer`--does it even *have* a `loading` property?

Comment: Is there a way to just say if the loadingBar is ACTIVE...?

Comment: If it doesn't have a `loading` property, *why are you trying to set its `loading` property?*

Comment: I just want a method to hide the UIActivitySheetView if nothing is loading anymore. Maybe just removeChild at end of SplashScene?

Comment: If you use methods, properties, and functions that actually exist, you may be more successful. Go check out the documentation for the classes you're using to determine what they can and can't do.

Comment: Yes I understand that now. I just want to know if removeChild the activity sheet would work.

Comment: removeChild won't work because it's not a node...how do I remove it after scenes switch?

Comment: `CCProgressTimer` does in fact inherit from `CCNode`, so it *is* a `CCNode`.

Comment: Oops I was removing activity by accident. CCProgressTimer is a node...sorry about that. Thanks for answering my questions. One last one - how do you format your text within comments?

Comment: Same way you do in your post--see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for info about formatting.

Answer (score 0):

try to forward declare your controller class in your view class's .h file

@class yourcontroller

@interface yourview....

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I've already done @class CCProgressTimer;
in the header file